# MATLAB - How to plot multiple timeseries (paleoclimate) with a common x axis and multiple stacked y axes?

Tags: geochemistry, matlab, paleoclimate

I'm trying to create figures in MatLab and am a reasonably new user, I'm wondering if there is a good way to make plots that use a common x-axis and then vertically stacked and alternating y-axes as in the picture below.

So far I have been using the subplot function and it's not really doing the trick for me.

Thanks!

[image: Example plot]

Comment: I don't think MATLAB allows you to create a plot like this at all. You can create a bunch of plots, save the MATLAB figure as .eps or .pdf files, open those files in Adobe Illustrator (or any vector-based program like it) and combine the lot into a single figure. What do you think about that approach? Would that answer your question? Be sure, though, to check out https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/stackedplot.html for a kind-of solution.

Comment: I don't think this is an earth science question, the method should work regardless of what data we're plotting. Stackoverflow may be a better place for this - you're more likely to have it seen by people proficient in matlab there.

Comment: Voting to close or migrate to Stackoverflow, this is a programming issue, not an earth science one.